# Maximum related to Nonnegative Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose $A$ is a fixed nonnegative $n\times n$ real matrix (i.e. $A_{ij}\geq0$ for all $i,j$). Then for any arbitrary $n$ positive real numbers $x_1,\ldots,x_n$, we denote:
$$F(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\min_i\frac{1}{x_i}\sum_{j=1}^n x_jA_{ij}$$
Frobenius Theorem tells us that there's always an inequality
$$F(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\leq\rho(A)$$
where $\rho(A)$ is the spectral radius of $A$.

Here my question is, what is the maximum of $F(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ ? Is it just $\rho(A)$ ? Or there's no maximum but a supremum? 
Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I am not sure about what is your question. Because the inequality given by you clearly shows that $F$ is bounded above by spectral radius and by taking $A=\mathbb{I}$ and $x_i=1$ for all $i$ the we can see that the upper bound is achieved.

Comment: @tessellation $A$ is fixed. It's a given matrix.

Comment: Now I get it. Is it just a matrix with non-negative integers or it has some special properties like being Orthogonal or Symmetric.

Comment: @WildChan the inequality you've written just gives an upper bound. The bound is not necessarily sharp.

Comment: @tessellation No other properties, just non-negative entries (not necessarily integers).

Comment: @S.B. Yup. So I want the exact maximum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not lead to a full solution you want, but it is worth rewriting the desired optimization as $$\sup_{t\geq 0,\mathbf{x}> \mathbf{0}} t\\
\text{subject to }(\mathbf{A}-t\mathbf{I})\mathbf{x}\geq \mathbf{0}.$$

**Update:** Let $t_0 = \frac{1}{2}\lambda_{\max}\left(\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{A}^T\right)$. For any $t>t_0$ and all $\mathbf{x}\ne \mathbf{0}$ we have $\mathbf{x}(\mathbf{A}-t\mathbf{I})\mathbf{x}^T<0$. Therefore, $(\mathbf{A}-t\mathbf{I})\mathbf{x}\geq \mathbf{0}$ cannot hold for any $\mathbf{x}>0$. So your optimal $t$ should be less than or equal to $t_0$.

Furthermore, for positive $A$ the maximum is the Perron-Frobenius eigenvalue (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem#Positive_matrices) item #6).

Comment: Thank you. I also deduced this yesterday. But how to use this result?

Comment: @WildChan: Did the update help?

Comment: Sorry that it's been a long time I'm away from the Internet. Your answer really does help, THX.

Answer (score 1):

You are essentially looking at collatz-weilandt formula. If your matrix $A$ is strictly positive or irreducible, then the maximum is the spectral radius.

Comment: Thanks. Cna you give me some resources on Collatz-Wielandt formula? Wikipedia doesn't talk a lot about this. What if $A$ isn't irreducible?

Comment: I was also looking for the same!!. I am not able to find it now. I will check it and let you know when time permits. Is your $A$ irreducible?

Comment: Actually not. This question arose when I was looking up Frobenius Theorem, and the only constraint on $A$ is non-negative.